# How to Make isBst function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
isBST :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isBST Null           = False
isBST (Node x t1 t2) = if (((isBST t1) < x) && ((isBST t2) > x)) then True else False
```

I want to make `isBST` function in Haskell, but it's not working.
What's wrong in my code?

```
[Error]
<interactive>:3:42: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          isBST :: forall a. Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
        at <interactive>:1:1-32
    • In the second argument of ‘(<)’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘(&&)’, namely ‘((isBST t1) < x)’
      In the expression: (((isBST t1) < x) && ((isBST t2) > x))
    • Relevant bindings include
        t2 :: Tree a (bound at <interactive>:3:18)
        t1 :: Tree a (bound at <interactive>:3:15)
        x :: a (bound at <interactive>:3:13)
        isBST :: Tree a -> Bool (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

Comment: `isBST t1` returns a `Bool`. It can not be compared with `x`

Comment: Don't write `if condition then True else False`, it's equivalent to `condition`. Rather, you should realize that this is impossible to do with a recursive function having your exact signature: you will need an auxiliary recursive function with a different signature, e.g. to return a boolean and the min/max values of the tree, since you need to know all of that.

Comment: `isBST Null` should return `True`; an empty tree is vacuously a binary search tree.

Comment: A simpler approach is to split this into two tasks: one, build a list of all the values in the tree with an in-order traversal, and two, check if that list is non-decreasing. It's *necessary* for each subtree to be a BST, but not *sufficient*.

Answer (score 1):

```hs
isBST :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
isBST Null = True
isBST (Node x t1 t2) = isBST t1 && isBST t2 && test t1 (<) && test t2 (>)
  where
    test Null _ = True
    test (Node v _ _) f = f v x
```

---

Update:

In your solution, there are several problems:

- `isBST Null = False`. All trees contain at least one `Null` Node. If `Null` is not a BST, no tree can be a BST.
- `(isBST t1) < x`. `isBST t1` returns a `Bool` value, which can not be compared with type `a`. That is just what the compile error message tells you. You should do these two things (check sub-trees and check the current node) separately.
- As @chi says, `if condition then True else False` is unnecessary. Just write `condition`.

/cc @JeremyCaney

Comment: Could you edit your answer to provide the OP—and any future readers—further explanation of what was wrong with the original code, and why the code you've contributed resolves the issues?